# Вырезать текст с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется следующая строка `feature/STR-874-dropPanel`
Необходимо получить `STR-874`
Подскажите, как это сделать с помощью regexp?

Comment: Если у вас всегда там строка `STR-874`, то ничего вырезать не нужно, её можно просто константой использовать, а если у вас там разные значения могут быть, то вам следует описать правило, по которому нужно доставать эту подстроку

Comment: STR - константа, а вот числовое значение будет меняться. Т.е грубо говоря правило такое - отрезать все, что до STR и все, что следует после последней цифры

Answer (score -1):

Возможно поможет использование групп:

```js
var str = 'feature/STR-874-dropPanel';

function parse(str) {
  var match = str.match(/STR-(\d+)/);
  return match[1];
}

console.log(parse(str));
```